# How to type a text that appears in LED usin nios2

Tags: assembly, monitor, led, nios

I am using intel FGPA monitor program "Nios 2" to implement a text on the LED. The LED is in DE10-Lite board.
I am not sure how to type a text to display it on the LED, for example I want to type "welcome".
Can I get a head start?

Comment: From a quick search it appears that DE10-Lite board contains only digit led display. Are you connecting some other LED display to the DE10-Lite?

Comment: no it is all on the board, and the digit can be manipulated to display letters or dash lines

Comment: you mean something like [this](https://github.com/dmadison/LED-Segment-ASCII#7-segment)? It's unclear what you're asking